# Angular ngMessage: Validate on form submit

Tags: angularjs

in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NPNK4JgzEIKzErsSYDsL?p=preview) there's a form with ngMessage validations. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- When the form is shown to the user, no error messages should be displayed
- On blur, if the field has errors, the message should be displayed
- When the form is submitted, if there are any fields with errors, then the error messages should be displayed.

In the plunk I have two issues: (1) the message is displayed when the form is initially shown, and (2) when no error messages and the user clicks on the button, the form is not submitted. What's wrong with the code?

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-minlength="5"
           ng-maxlength="20"
           required />
  </label>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" 
  ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);
app.controller('nameController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    alert('Form submitted - fields passed validation');

  };      
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to display validation messages using condition like e.g. ng-if

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="submitted || myForm.myName.$dirty" 
    ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (myForm.$valid) {
        alert('Form submitted - fields passed validation');
    }
};
```

and move ng-submit from button to form tag like:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
```

Comment: will this work if I am only working on validation in case of `$touched`

Answer (score 3):

Based on Kwarc's anwser, here is a little improvement since you can avoid using a `$scope` variable to know if your form is submitted. It also ensure a better behavior on error message display.

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="myForm.myName.$invalid && (myForm.$submitted || myForm.myName.$touched)" 
   ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
   <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
   <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
   <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
   if (myForm.$valid) {
       alert('Form submitted - fields passed validation');
   }
};
```

`myForm.$submitted` will be automatically set to true

and finally, apply the same form submit method on form tag:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was simply enough to use in the ng-if the $submitted state of the form (example is barebones):

```js
// and in the submit btn

scope.submit = function() {
  scope.myForm.$setSubmitted();
  if (scope.myForm.$valid) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

```html
<div ng-if="myForm.$submitted || myForm.attr.$touched" ng-messages="myForm.attr.error">
  <!-- messages with ngMessages -->
</div>
```